# Return of 2D Brownian motion to the origin

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

In what follows $B$ denotes two-dimensional Brownian motion and $\mathbb{B}(0,z)$ denotes the disk with radius $z$ centered at the origin. I also define the hitting time $\tau_C = \inf\{t \geq 0: B_t \in C\}$. It then follows that

$$P^x\{\tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,r)} < \tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,R)^{\mathsf{c}}}\} = \frac{\log{R} - \log{\lvert x\rvert}}{\log{R} - \log{r}}$$

for $0 < r < \lvert x\rvert < R$. In other words, the expression above is the probability that the two-dimensional Brownian motion started at $x$ enters the ball with radius $r$ before it exits the ball with radius $R$.

Using this expression I want to compute $P^x\{\tau_{\{0\}} < \infty\}$, namely the probability that the two-dimensional Brownian motion started at $x$ hits the origin in finite time.

The double limit 
$$\lim_{R \to \infty}\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\log{R} - \log{\lvert x\rvert}}{\log{R} - \log{r}} = 0$$
gives the right answer. But the double limit 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{\log{R} - \log{\lvert x\rvert}}{\log{R} - \log{r}} = 1$$
gives the wrong answer. I am trying to understand what is going wrong in this latter approach.

First, 
$$\lim_{R \to \infty}P^x\{\tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,r)} < \tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,R)^{\mathsf{c}}}\} = P^x\{\tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,r)} < \infty\} = 1$$

But somehow it is not true that
$$1_{\tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,r)}(\omega) < \infty}(\omega) \to 1_{\tau_{\{0\}}(\omega) < \infty}(\omega) \label{a}\tag{1}$$
as $r \to 0$. If it were true, then $P^x\{\tau_{\{0\}} < \infty\}$ would be $1$, which is wrong. But I don't see why $\ref{a}$ does not hold. Can someone explain the error in my reasoning?

Comment: Think of continuous paths $\omega$ that pass arbitrarily close to $0$ but never hit $0$. The law $P^x$ gives weight $1$ to such paths.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I understand that but I don't see how that explains why the convergence in $(1)$ does not hold.

Comment: @Calculon: For such $\omega$ we have $\tau_{B(0,r)}(\omega) < \infty$ for all $r > 0$ and $\tau_{\{0\}}(\omega) = \infty$.  The left side of (1) is identically 1 and the right side is 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes but I assume you arrived at that conclusion by first letting $R$ tend to infinity and second by letting $r \to 0$ in that expression with logarithms. I mean how do you know the lhs of $(1)$ is identically $1$ and the rhs is identically $0$ in the first place?

Comment: By "identically 1" I mean "for such an $\omega$, LHS is 1 for every $r > 0$ and RHS is 0."  I am not varying $\omega$ and indeed my statement has nothing to do with probability.  It simply points out why (1) is not necessarily a true statement pointwise.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you. Sorry that I misunderstood your statement. But then why is the right order of limits right? I mean if I need to let $r\to 0$ first, then I guess the following convergence must be necessarily true:
$$1_{\tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,r)}(\omega) < \tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,R)^{\mathsf{c}}}(\omega)}(\omega) \to 1_{\tau_{\{0\}}(\omega) < \tau_{\mathbb{B}(0,R)^{\mathsf{c}}}(\omega)}(\omega)$$
For the set of $\omega$s on which the lhs of the equation above is $1$ for every $r > 0$, is it necessarily true that the rhs is also $1$? I am having trouble picturing this.